# Matching the file path of a file in bash

Tags: bash, macos

I have a series of custom wallpaper in a folder:

```
/Library/Desktop Pictures/Custom/custom1.jpg
/Library/Desktop Pictures/Custom/custom2.jpg
/Library/Desktop Pictures/Custom/custom3.jpg
```

I want to run a script that will check to see if the current mac desktop wallpaper is one of the custom wallpapers in that folder.

I managed to script a working solution. I grab the file and path of the current desktop image and then run a second command to grab the path and then match that. I was just curious for my own learning if there is a better way to approach the problem.

Current solution:

```
wallpaper=$(osascript -e 'tell app "finder" to get posix path of (get desktop picture as alias)')
path=$(dirname "$wallpaper")

if [[ $path == "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Custom" ]]; then
  echo "<result>SET</result>"
else
  echo "<result>NOT SET</result>"
fi
```

Comment: What does “better” mean?

Comment: If your code does what you want it to do, and passes syntax checks (like at https://www.shellcheck.net/), move on to your next project :)

Comment: As an alternative there would be a property you can get that'd give the path - without having to interact with the UI directly.  This method also won't work if you have multiple users and the current UI user is not the user running the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the variable `path` only for testing it inside the `if`, you could also write

```
if [[ $wallpaper == "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Custom"/* ]]
```